# Outlook / Office365 : Can I create "right-click" Quick Action or Step to remove item from calendar or run a macro

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I'd like to create a Quick Action or Quick Step that either removes the currently selected meeting cancellation msg from my calendar (and deletes the message from the inbox), or runs a macro.

The "Quick Actions" configuration options seems to be severely limited; the "Quick Steps" config option less so.

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, based on my test, neither Quick action and Quick steps can achieve your request. But we could set the followings to remove ranceled meetings automatically:

File>Options>Calendar

select “Automatically accept meeting requests and remove canceled meetings”.

[image]

From now on, Outlook will help you remove the canceled meeting automatically. But there is a shortcoming, namely Outlook will accept all the meeting invitations automatically as well.

Comment: Close enough!  Marking as answer.